# angularjs ajax post method params preparation

Tags: ajax, angularjs

```
{
    "address":"J.P.NAGAR",
    "payment_type": 
    "paymentMethod",
    "time":"2015-09-12 03:22:31",
    "name":"Madhava Raju",
    "tel":"9591865409",
    "userId":"66",
    "deviceId":"66",
    "type":"cod",
    "seats_number":"1",
    "table_id":"2",
    "products[0]":{
        "id":"1397529704",
        "sl":1,"topping":[{"1397879078":"1441207278"}],
        "instruction":"Poora"
    }
}
```

How can I send the above data to the server using angular ajax with POST method and as URL parameters.

Comment: value has json object in my case instead of string this is the only problem any suggestions please...

Comment: not sure what you're looking to do here.   can you give an example of what you would like that url to look like in your question e.g?  www.yourserver.com/apiurl?address=J.P.NaGar&payment_type=paymentMethod...   I'm not sure there's a library out there that converts json to query params  tbh. but if your needs are simple it's probably to too hard to roll your own

Answer (score 0):

The following sends a POST request:

```
$http.post(url, data, options).then(onSuccess, onError);
```

- `url` beigin the remote server url, you can also put parameters here, like so `?address=J.P.NAGAR&payment_type=paymentMethod`, etc...
- `data` being the object you wish to send via POST, I assume you want to POST the object you specified in your post, so put it here.
- `options` are optional, you can leave it out if you want. It can be
  used for timeout and similar.
- `onSuccess` and `onError` are callbacks (functions) to handle the reponse
  from the server.